# <video> object within SVG floats outside it's foreign object container

Tags: html, css, svg, video, html5-video

I have an svg object im my HTML page which contains several foreign objects. All of which work as I expect them to and scale responsibly along with the svg, aside from the video element.

The video element does not respect it's container objects width/height. Neither am I able to use the default video control options, the play menu is displayed but not interactable. **This problem only occurs in Chrome**, Firefox displays the element as expected and the video is playable.

[printscreen comparing chrome (fail) with firefox (success)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxr4n.png)

*What I've already tried to solve this problem (with no success):*

- Replace  object with iFrame (same problem)
- Use Jquery video plugin to handle CSS (like jQuery.fitvids)
- Wrap video in container div (tried position responsive/absolute/fixed/..)
- Wrap video in second foreignObject element
- Practically any possible combination for x, y, width and height on both video object as it's container. (If I use non responsive values for width and height I can position it but I need the responsiveness as it's parent can change size, also the menu to play and pause the video still won't work)

```css
#svgContainer {
  width:500px;
  height:250px;
  background-color:#34ff00;
}

#videoTitle {
  font-size:80px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#videoObject {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  object-fit:contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="svgContainer">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 959.8 540">
    <g id="DIA_REGULARMEDIAVIDEO">
      <foreignObject x="50" y="25" width="655" height="69">
        <div id="videoTitle">My video</div>
      </foreignObject>
      <foreignObject x="0" y="120" width="959.8" height="420">
          <video id="videoObject" x="0" y="0" width="300" controls="" preload="">
          <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
          </video>
      </foreignObject>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you reported this to Chrome's bugtracker, or checked the bugtracker to see whether someone else has reported it?

Comment: Why not just put the video directly in the <div> rather than in the <svg> at all?

Comment: I reported it to bugtracker.. 
The svg contains an entire presentation (retreived from an external source) it contains images, text,.. over multiple layers. Separating the video from the rest of the presentation would be a last resort hacky "solution". It would require plenty Javascript to simulate it being part of the presentation.

Comment: I do have the exact same issues on Chrome.